# Creating a sub HWND handle from an existant window

Tags: c#, winforms, hwnd

I have a winform window in which I am drawing manually/programmatically, I would like to provide a HWND handle to a process I cannot modify that expressly awaits a win32 HWND (*this process is then going to draw its own things in my window, using the HWND handle*).

The important point of detail is that **I want the HWND to point at a certain location in my window.**

Is there a way to create a new *artificial* HWND which would point a particular zone of my window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get a HWND to a window and every control like buttons checkboxes etc are also considered windows. 
So if there is no control located at the "zone" where you want to get a HWND to, that is not possible.
But if there is a groupbox on that place for instance, it is possible.

You want to draw to a certain area.
So why not just get a handle to the window and with the use of GetClientRect and GetWindowRect and draw to the x/y coordinates you want.

Comment: So maybe, should I create a dummy control at the intended location.

Comment: Actually as I said, I cannot change the code that will use the handle. This code will take the handle and draw from location (0;0). So I have to give another offset-ed handle.

Comment: so you also have no control over the device handle?